# How to fix 0xc000007b error which occurs in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, installation, compilation

I've run through an error with opening my compiled app (opengl project for graphics course - there are dependencies such as assimp, GLEW, GLFW, GLM). It cannot be started. I have tried to solve this problem using Google and found some hints, which I have followed:

- updated .NET frameworks for x64 and x86 and Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable
- run chkdsk to check whether something was corrupted  - everything's fine
- updated DirectX, Adobe and Windows
- checked DLL files by running cmd command

None of above helped.
Compilation was run in debug mode for Win32 platform in Visual Studio 2019.
All configuration was set correctly - every library needed for the project was included.
The assimp was set up by following these steps:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

-main/
--bus-simulator/
---Debug/
---res/
---src/
--Dependencies/
---assimp/
----include/
headers from assimp source code
----lib/
---GLEW/
----lib/
----include/
headers from GLEW source code
-----GL/
---GLFW/
----lib/
----include/
headers from GLFW source code
---GLM/
headers from GLM source code

At the very first start, I cloned the repository from github, added the Dependencies folder and then I could start the app. When I tried to compile it again some time after, this error (0xc000007b) occurred. The output:

```
„bus-simulator.exe” (Win32): załadowano „C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll”.   
„bus-simulator.exe” (Win32): załadowano „C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll”.   
„bus-simulator.exe” (Win32): załadowano  
 „C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll”. 
„bus-simulator.exe” (Win32): załadowano „C:\Program Files\AVAST  
 Software\Avast\x86\aswhook.dll”.    
„bus-simulator.exe” (Win32): załadowano „C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll”.   
„bus-simulator.exe” (Win32): załadowano „C:\Windows\SysWOW64\win32u.dll”.   
„bus-simulator.exe” (Win32): załadowano „C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll”.   
„bus-simulator.exe” (Win32): załadowano „C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll”.   
„bus-simulator.exe” (Win32): załadowano „C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll”.  
„bus-simulator.exe” (Win32): załadowano „C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll”.   
„bus-simulator.exe” (Win32): załadowano „C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll”.   
Wątek 0x3c6c zakończył działanie z kodem -1073741701 (0xc000007b).  
Wątek 0x3f8c zakończył działanie z kodem -1073741701 (0xc000007b).  
Program „[5276] bus-simulator.exe” zakończył działanie z kodem -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
```

Another project downloaded from the Internet without assimp compiles and works in Visual Studio 2019 environment.
I would be eternally grateful if someone could help me.

[image]

edit1:
Are there any sites where I could download these missing files (seems like assimp-vc142-mt.dll and two other files are missing)?. I have checked it once more and this assimp .dll file is where it should be, in Debug folder with .exe file.

[image]

edit2: I have run cmake CMakeLists.txt and there is output in powershell reporting something about zlib.

Comment: `0xc000007b` means you are trying to mix 64-bit and 32-bit modules (exe / dll) in the same process - this is not possible.  Ensure every thing is compiled for 64-bit (or 32-bit).  Please read [ask] and post all errors as text.

Comment: I believe `0xc000007b` means you are likely mixing 32 and 64 bit with your dlls. Since your program is 32 bits you are somehow putting the 64 bit dlls in the path.

Comment: Also since you are using msvc, make sure if the library provides Debug and Release libraries and dlls make sure that you use them in the correct configuration. It's in most cases for c++ software its not safe to mix and match these.

Comment: @RichardCritten I have downloaded all of these Dependencies' subfolders (GLM,GLFW,GLEW,assimp) for 32-bit. Where to look for such inconsistencies then?

Comment: It may be that you compiled assimp in the x64 configuration. Or perhaps you did not copy the .dlls to the same location as your executable and windows is finding a 64 bit version of a required dll in one of the folders in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: @drescherjm I have compiled it using command: cmake -A win32. My friend done the same and it worked fine.

Comment: Check the folder containing your executable to make sure you put the correct dlls in that folder.

Comment: @drescherjm I have tried this solution and it didn't work.

Comment: See if this program tells you anything about a missing dll: [https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236912/discussion-between-code-rushh-and-drescherjm).

Comment: Note that if you executed the `cmake ...` command wrongly the first time to set the generator you need to clear the cmake cache file to reconfigure.

Comment: As an alternate you could use vcpkg to build this. It defaults to 32 bit builds.

Comment: ***C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\x86\aswhook.dll*** You may want to try disabling your AV. Perhaps it is causing the issue by  blocking the dll.

Comment: Do you mean adding exception files (here the whole project) which will be not tracked by AV?

Comment: You can try turning it completely off to see if that helps.

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Comment: Is it possible to download these .dll files from somewhere and paste them into the project?

Comment: ***edit2: I have run cmake CMakeLists.txt and there is output in powershell reporting something about zlib.*** I don't think anything in that is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

While `0xc000007b` means you're mixing 32/64 bits, it can also sometimes be thrown at you when the problem is indeed that you're missing a dependency (.dll, should be `0xc0000139`). [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) can help track it down.